# ypchsh not changing to some shells

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh

I am currently in bash but I want to change my shell to tcsh. I used ypchsh, entered my password when prompted and then changed the login shell to /bin/tcsh. And it seemed like it worked because I get a message that says "The login shell has been changed on [domain]". Then I logged out and logged back in. I did echo $0 to check my current shell but it says I'm still in /bin/bash. However, when I do echo $SHELL I get /bin/tcsh. And when I do ps, it shows that bash is running instead of tcsh.

Other trouble shooting steps taken: Tried doing the same steps to switch to different shells like sh and ksh which works. However, changing to csh gives me the same result as trying to change to tcsh. Checked /etc/shells and tcsh is listed. I also tried exec tcsh but the system still running bash.

I am trying to do this on a school account so maybe there is a permission issue. Although one of my classmate was able to get his account to change shell. If not permission is there like file that I need to config?

```
[user@machine ~]> echo $0
/bin/bash
[user@machine ~]> echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
[user@machine ~]> ypchsh
Changing NIS account information for user on machine
Please enter password:

Changing login shell for user on machine
To accept the default, simply press return. To use the
system's default shell, type the word "none".
Login shell [/bin/tcsh]: /bin/tcsh

The login shell has been changed on machine

[user@machine ~]> logout

[user@machine ~]> echo $0
/bin/bash
[user@machine ~]> echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
[user@machine ~]> FOO=BAR
[user@machine ~]> ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14549 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
14780 pts/21   00:00:00 ps
[user@machine ~]> exec /bin/tcsh
[user@machine ~]> echo $0
/bin/bash
[user@machine ~]> echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
[user@machine ~]> FOO=BAR
[user@machine ~]>

[user@machine ~]> uname -a
Linux machine 2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Jun 20 00:48:23 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[user@machine ~]> /bin/ls -ld
drwx--s--x 49 user group 4096 Sep  1 13:08 .
[user@machine ~]> /bin/*sh
/bin/csh: /bin/csh: cannot execute binary file
[user@machine ~]> /usr/bin/*sh
Usage: amuFormat.sh <Card Type> <drive>
<Card Type> has to be defined in amuFormat.sh itself
<drive> has to be defined in mtools.conf
```

Comment: You do all these secondary steps to see what shell you’re running — what does the ***primary*** evidence say? What happens if you type `FOO=BAR`? What shell are you really running? And seriously? You tried `exec tcsh` and you’re still in bash? I feel like you’re not telling us the whole story.

Comment: @Scott I'm not very familiar with the Linux systems, can you explain how I can find the "primary evidence" and what you mean by typing in FOO=BAR? I also posted a history of commands I made.

Comment: (0) Thanks for providing the update, but it would be clearer if you would delete the `>` characters and insert `$  ` before the shell commands.  It’s best if you copy from your terminal and paste into Super User. (Of course it’s OK to redact sensitive information like your username and machine name.) But if your shell prompt changes, show that. (1) You say you’re not very familiar with the Linux systems. I have to wonder how much you understand about the \*nix shells, and why you want to change yours. (2) When I say type `FOO=BAR`, I mean type `FOO=BAR` (followed by Enter) at the shell prompt.

Comment: I updated and pasted what I've done in terminal. Tried FOO=BAR but it doesn't seem like it did anything. I don't know anything about nix shells and I need to be in tcsh because exercises in class are done in tcsh and it would be easier to follow if my shell is the same.

Comment: Ah, but you don't need to make it your _primary_ shell just for that, do you? Any shell can be just launched from any other shell like a regular program.

Comment: (1) Thanks for clarifying your situation (why you want / need to use tcsh).  But grawity is right — if you just need to do some stuff in tcsh, don’t change shells (with chsh); just run tcsh.  (2) Thanks for updating your session report (showing the shell prompts and trying `FOO=BAR`).  You’re getting into a tricky area — ``echo "$0"``, ``echo "$SHELL"``, and `ps` are all, as I said, secondary evidence — they can give misleading responses.  The fact that `FOO=BAR` seems not to do anything is normal for a member of the Bourne shell family (sh, bash, ksh). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you were in a member of the C shell family (csh and tcsh), `FOO=BAR` would give you an error message. (3) The fact that your shell prompt doesn’t change, and `FOO=BAR` doesn’t give you an error message, after you’ve (tried to) run tcsh, says that this is not a ypchsh problem, this is a tcsh problem.  It’s a mess; this does not look like a common problem (i.e., it’s unusual).  If you want to continue pursuing this issue here, you need to give us more information.  For example: what’s the overall setup?  I mean, do you (i.e., you and your classmate(s)) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  have individual PCs running some form of Unix (and these PCs are in a network using YP/NIS or NIS+), and your problem is *on* your individual PC?  Has your classmate tried logging in on your PC, or vice versa?  Or are you using ssh, PuTTY, or something similar to login from a PC to a remote / central computer that is running some form of Unix?  Or something else (e.g., using terminals to login to a remote / central computer)?  Either way, it might help us if you would run the following commands and report the output: `uname -a`,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  ``/bin/ls -ld /bin/*sh /usr/bin/*sh | grep -v '\.sh$'``, `ls -l /proc/$$`, and `cat /proc/$$/cmdline  &&  echo`. These might give us enough information to be able to give you an answer, or they might just suggest more questions to ask. Sorry; I can’t give you a guarantee. (4) Since I can’t guarantee that we will be able to answer your question, you might be better off asking your instructor or your local system administrator for help.

Comment: @grawity I tried exec /bin/tcsh and did the FOO=BAR test but nothing happened as shown in the command history posted.

Comment: @Scott I tried what I explained I did on the post originally on a CentOS machine which didn't work. And then I tried doing those steps on the machine that my friend got it to work and on another machine but neither worked. So it might be an account issue. I've only tried the steps you suggested on a terminal through PuTTY.  I'll post the results for /bin/ls -ld and .../bin/*sh above but the other ones I worry might be too reveling to post publicly is there something you are looking for in those results. And how do I find the overall setup and such?

Comment: (1) `/bin/ls -ld /bin/*sh /usr/bin/*sh | grep -v '\.sh$'` is all one command.  My purpose in asking you to run that command is to see whether `/bin/tcsh` is a link to `/bin/bash` on your system, because that would explain what you’re seeing.  (If `/bin/tcsh` is small — less than 1000 bytes — that would also be a red flag.)  (2) I asked for the `uname -a` because that might guide us in directions to look. (3) `cat /proc/$$/cmdline` might give us a clue as to how the shell is being invoked. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  `ls -l /proc/$$` will tell us what you have in `/proc`, which might also be able to provide us with useful information. (4) By “overall setup” I mean stuff that’s so obvious [to you] that you’re not bothering to mention it: are you all using the same machine (remotely), or are you using individual Unix/Linux PCs, and other logistic stuff that would probably have been explained to you on the first day of class (or the first lab session, if appropriate). I think I explained that in my comment (7 hours ago).

Comment: @Scott I figured out why it keeps going back to bash! I compared my .cshrc file with my friend's and saw that I had "exec /bin/bash -l" in there and he didn't. Not sure what I did to put it there but I removed it and I can ypchsh into tcsh now. I checked with FOO=BAR and I got an error back so it works now. Thank you for your time and detailed explanations!

Comment: Ah; obvious in hindsight, but I might have never guessed that.  Thanks for updating me.  You can share your discovery with more people by posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my shell keeps going back to bash and even preventing me from using exec to get into tcsh was because in the .cshrc file there was a line that says `exec /bin/bash -l` in there. To fix this I removed that line and from that point on I can switch shells.